# How to clip a RGBA raster with another single band raster using QGIS or GDAL

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, clip, rgb

I have a RGBA raster and I would like to set all the data over the continents to transparent. I have a single band raster where land is equal to 0 and ocean is equal to 1. Normally if I had a single band raster, I would multiply the single band raster with the above mask raster, in raster calculator, and this would remove the land data. How do I do the same thing with a RGBA raster in QGIS or GDAL, where the result would be 0, 0, 0, 0 for the four bands?

Comment: Have you tried multiplying just the 4th band with the songle band raster?